# How can I perform an inject operation in CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

I'm trying to do exactly this, but with CoffeeScript:

```
# ruby:
items.map {|item| item.price * item.quantity }.reduce(:+)
```

What I have so far:

```
# coffeescript:
item.price * item.quantity for item in items
```

How can I sum all the items in the array? More generally, how can I perform any operation across all the items in the array (in Ruby this would be `inject` or `reduce`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it. It's done with [`reduce`](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/reducing-arrays)

```
(item.price * item.quantity for item in items).reduce (x, y) -> x + y
```

Comment: Note that `reduce()` doesn't have the best browser support in IE.

Comment: @alex Interesting... since CoffeeScript is so thin I though it was cross browser compatible. Fortunately IE is not a problem here, but I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a portable `reduce`, use Underscore: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reduce

Comment: @alfonso: CoffeeScript being "thin" is exactly the problem here: `reduce` has nothing to do with CoffeeScript, it is a method from the ECMAScript core library which was added in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @alfonso Alternatively, if you don't want to include Underscore.js (or you prefer the native syntax), yo can add a `Array.prototype.reduce` implementation as the one listed [in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility). Or, if you find yourself using many of this ECMAScript 5 functions, you could use a "shim", like [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/),that will add all those awesome things :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a general [reduce](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/reducing-arrays) function, but for just the accumulator, you can do

```
sum = 0
sum += item.price * item.quantity for item in items
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general reduce function might look like this:

```
total = ((agg = 0) ->
  agg + item.price * item.quantity
)(total, item) for item in items
```

or

```
result = ((aggregate = 'default value') ->
  // function body changing, then returning aggregate
  aggregate
)(result, i) for i in some_array
```